# how to convert Xcode 3.2.5 code to Xcode 4

Tags: xcode

How to convert the Xcode 3.2.5 version code to the Xcode 4?

Comment: Xcode 4 is still unreleased, and therefore under Apple’s non-disclosure agreement. Visit [devforums.apple.com](http://devforums.apple.com) to discuss it.

Comment: 1. Xcode4 ist still covered by the NDA you signed with apple. 2. Not necessary.

Comment: But I need to deploy my app to test in iPhone 4, which is coded in XCOde 3.2.5 and It is perfectly working in ipod touch...!!

Comment: I mean XCode4 Preview --> XCode 4GM Seed

Comment: @RKK: you won't be able to deploy *anything* if Apple revokes your developer status for breaking an NDA.

Comment: Why do so many people feel the need to be the NDA Police? If RKK is breaking an agreement with Apple, that is between him and Apple.

Comment: At this point Xcode 4 is public, but the question is not clear. Are you having a specific problem building a project made with an earlier version of Xcode to Xcode 4? Or running an app on iOS 4?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to convert any code. Xcode is a development environment, not a compiler.

(Of course, the word "shouldn't" has been the enemy of programmers for centuries.)